# Searching items in a folder by content does not search in .json files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search, json

Using the "Content:" search filter under windows 10, i am able to find files that contain a string, this worked for me with excel tables, word docs and simple txt files.
However, now i am trying to find a keyword throughout a number of .json files, and i get no returns.

Why is that? I can open jsonfiles with the editor just normally, why cant windows run a plain text search on them? And more important - is there a way to fix this?

I guess i could write a script that just loads the json data and filters the content but... I dont understand why it doesnt work.

EDIT: I already change the indexing to file content btw, and in the list it says that it searches .json files too.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: nope, ended up writing a script that renames all json files to .txt, then searching, then renaming it back...

Answer (score 4):

This is how I resolved:
Windows menu >> Type "Index" to find Indexing Options >> Advanced >> File Types Tab >> find the json extension and change it to "Index Properties and File contents.

I hope it works for you too

Comment: this seems does not work